# How to wait for 2 selectors with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

In my use case, the only way to know when a page is loaded is to wait for 2 selectors.

What's the best way to do that with CasperJS?

Here is my solution:

```
casper.waitUntilVisible2 = function(selector1, selector2, then, onTimeout, timeout) {
  casper.waitUntilVisible(selector1, function () {
    casper.waitUntilVisible(selector2, then, onTimeout, timeout)
  }, onTimeout, timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest some improvement so that the function can be used for chaining by returning `this` and actually using `this` to make it easier to add this function to different `casper` instances within one script. Otherwise it's fine.

```
casper.waitUntilVisible2 = function(selector1, selector2, then, onTimeout, timeout) {
  this.waitUntilVisible(selector1, function () {
    this.waitUntilVisible(selector2, then, onTimeout, timeout)
  }, onTimeout, timeout);
  return this;
}
```

What you can also try is to only use the second selector.

```
casper.waitUntilReappears = function(selector, then, onTimeout, timeout) {
  this.waitWhileVisible(selector, function () {
    this.waitUntilVisible(selector, then, onTimeout, timeout)
  }, onTimeout, timeout);
  return this;
}
```

Although this might fail if the selectors are changed faster than 20 ms.

Comment: It doesn't work because the 2nd selector is already present on the previous page, so I need to wait for the first one and then I need to wait for the second that is loaded asynchronously.

Comment: I see, haven't thought about that case. I changed my answer. So, if it works for you it is the shortest function for doing this.

Comment: By the way, is there an actual page load or is this a single page application? Because if there is an actual page load, you can use a combination of `then` followed by `waitUntilVisible(selector2)`. I think you need to describe what your specific use case is otherwise I'm going to guess what is best in that case and lose interest.

Comment: single page application (angular)